# hard drive doesn't appear as device

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, usb

I have an Acer Aspire R11 combination Laptop / Tablet. It has a 32 Gb harddrive with a few partitions. Windows 8.1 is installed on it. I recently had an issue with partitioning. I decided to use an Ubuntu Live USB stick to first try to repair the partitions - and, if that failed, wipe the drive and install Ubuntu to it.

The problem is, it doesn't see the internal drive (or any of its partitions) at all. It only sees the USB stick and any other USB drives I connect. There is nothing that even shows up in `/dev` that looks like it might be the drive. Only `sda` and `sda1` exist, which are the USB stick and its primary partition. Even running gparted, it only shows `/dev/sda`. I know this laptop has a weird soldered in SD/MMC chip as a hard drive, but I would still expect it to show up as a normal device. How can I get Ubuntu to recognize the drive exists?

Note: I have tried in both UEFI and Legacy modes.

Added on 4/24/2016 per comment, here is the `dmesg` ouput:

```
[    0.069652] SCSI subsystem initialized
[   10.284914] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 249)
[   10.802897] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[   12.258989] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Verbatim STORE N GO       1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[   12.260571] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   12.260974] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 15669248 512-byte logical blocks: (8.02 GB/7.47 GiB)
[   12.261628] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   12.261632] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[   12.262293] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[   12.262296] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   12.265565]  sda: sda1
[   12.267592] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

"VERBATIM STORE-N-GO" is the USB stick I am booting from. Nothing else appears to be listed, it's like the hard drive for the laptop just disappeared.

Additional information:
I had to prove the hard drive is still there, so I F2 booted into the UEFI settings. The hard drive shows up, it's identified as `EMMC: HBG4e 32G` maybe that information will help.

Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    1   7.5G  0 part /cdrom
loop0    7:0    0 975.9M  1 loop /rofs
```

Not sure what `loop0` is there for. My understanding was that is only used when mounting an `.iso` or other image file as a drive. Not doing that in this case. But no MMC devices.

Output of `lshw` with `LC_MESSAGE=POSIX`

```
  *-usb:0
       description: Mass storage device
       product: Mass Storage
       vendor: Generic
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: scsi0
       version: 1.06
       serial: 5FEAAEA0
       capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
     *-disk
          description: SCSI Disk
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          size: 3851MiB (4038MB)
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=07578645
```

Note: I'm using a different USB stick, one with Lubuntu 16.04 live. I kept Ubuntu 14.04 on the Verbatim Store-N-Go incase I couldn't get 16.04 working.

output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 2284 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 21)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22ca (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 2292 (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
```

Comment: What's the output of `sudo dmesg | grep -iEe 'ahci|scsi|\<ata|\<sd'`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I added the output of the command to the original question.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't really fruitful. I just read that your computer has an MMC device. Is there anything device node matching `/dev/mmc*`? What does `lsblk` show? Maybe `sudo dmesg | grep -iFe mmc` produces interesting kernel log entries.

Comment: Looking around a bit I found that there should be a device node `/dev/mmcblk0`. What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f /dev/mmcblk[0-9]`? You should be able to use GParted or other partitioning and data recovery tools on that. You can force GParted to use that device with `gksu gparted /dev/mmcblk0`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: believe it or not I already tried that before your comment. That dmesg command gives no output. Also nothing matches /dev/mmc*. Is there some sort of MMC driver not included on the Live ISO that I need? Another nugget of info, in case it matters: I have to disable ACPI in order to boot to ubuntu (black screen otherwise), but I don't think that would affect any drives.

Comment: I can find reports of success with Ubuntu 15.10 on the Aspire R11. Maybe you can try that instead. It's possible that 16.04 has a regression that prevents it from using the internal MMC device out of the box.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What's the output of `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX lshw -C storage -C disk`? That way we may at least be able to identify the storage controller of the MMC device and the responsible device driver.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: ran the command, still just recognizes my USB stick. In both 14.04 and 16.04. FYI I was running 14.04 before, because the R11 doesn't meet the recommended specs for 16.04. I decided to do Lubuntu 16.04 instead. Same issue. I was avoiding 15.10 since it's not LTS, but I guess I'll just have to try. Unfortunately, it takes me more than a day to download a distro with my internet connection.

Comment: @DavidFoerster 15.10 gives me the same problem. Wondering if somebody somewhere has a driver for this "MMC device" that's on this laptop

Comment: It doesn't have a `hard drive` it has a 32GB SSD. You could have bough a model with 500GB hard drive though. Reading the reviews of this laptop / tablet hybrid left me with a negative impression.

Comment: i agree with David , you need to find the driver for the MMC chipset that provides access to that 32gb mmc. I wonder if secure boot is doing something odd with hiding it , maybe you could disable secure boot or try a signed ubuntu image. When you do finally see the  MMC be very carefull not to damage the UEFI partitions as you could end up with brick.

Comment: Yes, mine has the 32 GB MMC device. Not a great design. I already tried disabling secure boot and it still could not see it, unfortunately. I "think" I'm using a signed image as it boots fine to Ubuntu even with secure boot enabled.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a Linux driver for the MMC chipset. If someone could find that driver and point me to it, that would certainly suffice for me for an accepted answer.

Comment: can you post full dmesg?

Comment: dmesg output is too long

Comment: You can upload longer listings should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and link to them in the question.

Comment: It looks like Linux doesn't detect any storage controllers besides USB. There are no (S)ATA, SCSI or MMC controllers whatsoever. This is no driver issue! Linux doesn't even see a suitable device.